# Jenkins restart without interrupting currently running jobs

Tags: jenkins

There has a chance to restart Jenkins with stops the job or once job is completed. But is there any command or process to restart Jenkins without interrupt running job.

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins jobs are not in interrupted if you run them on Jenkins agents and not a controller.

What you look for is `safeRestart` which:

> Puts Jenkins into the quiet mode, wait for existing builds to be
> completed, and then restart Jenkins

Read more [here](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci-kb/latest/client-and-managed-masters/how-to-start-stop-or-restart-your-instance) and Jenkins docs.

Comment: I always wondered, what if my long-running job is executing on an agent and I restart the controller. Will the restarted controller pick up the long-running job continue showing log progress or not?